# How to delete a specific txt file using php

Tags: php, html, arrays

I've figured out how to make an array of each of my posts so that the txt file is unique, but I'm stuck on trying to figure out how to delete it. This is my progress so far:

Index.php:

```
      <?php

    $fileNames = glob("*.txt");
    $posts = array();

    foreach($fileNames as $fileName) {
      $post = file($fileName);
      array_push($posts, $post);
    }

    $postNum = 0;
    foreach($posts as $post) {

      $i = 1;
      $fname = $fileNames[$postNum];
      foreach($post as $line) {

        if ($i==1) {
          echo "<h1 style=\"padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;\">$line</h1>";
        } else {
          echo "<p style=\"padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px; color:#4d4d4d;\">$line</p>";
          echo "<form action=\"deletepost.php\" method=\"get\" style=\"padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Delete Post\"><input type='hidden' name='filename' value='".$fname."'></form>";
        }
        $i++;
      }



      $postNum++;

    }


  ?>
```

Deletepost.php:

```
    <?php
session_start();
    if($_SESSION['authenticated'] != true) {
        header("Location: login.php");
        die();
    }

?>
```

I know I have to use $_REQUEST['filename']; somewhere in deletepost.php, but that's as far as I've gotten. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: see php unlink http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) function. You can add this logic :

Deletepost.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['authenticated'] != true || !isset($_GET['filename'])) {
        header("Location: login.php");
        die();
    }

    $filename = $_GET['filename'];

    if(file_exists($filename)) {
        unlink($filename);
    }
?>
```

But I strongly advise you to check and recheck the $filename value, and see if the file to delete is not sensible (ex : http://yoursite.com/deletepost.php?filename=../index.php will delete your index.php file !)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can delete files using`unlink()` in PHP, returning true on success and false on.. not success.

```
    if (file_exists($_REQUEST['filename']) unlink($_REQUEST['filename']);
```